# mock api call in a custom hook using react test library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have written a custom hook and inside it's useEffect function I am calling an API and set the result into state. Here is my custom hook:

```js
export const useGetUsers = (searchParams?: any | undefined, userId?: string) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<{
    data: readonly any[] | null;
    loading: boolean;
  }>({
    data: [],
    loading: true,
  });

  const parsedSearchParams = {
    limit: 100,
    ...(searchParams || {}),
  };
  const searchParamStr = `?${makeQueryStringFromObject(parsedSearchParams)}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    userRequest('users', 'get', null, searchParamStr)
      .then(result => {
        setUsers({
          data: result?.data,
          loading: false,
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setUsers({
          data: null,
          loading: false,
        });
      });
  }, [userId, searchParamStr]);

  return { users, setUsers };
};
```

I want my test to get through `.then()`. but for some reason it does not. here is my test:

```js
    test('when the call is a success', async () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(ES, 'userRequest');
        const returnPromise = Promise.resolve({data: ['a']})
        ES.userRequest = jest.fn(() => returnPromise);

        const { result, waitFor} = renderHook(() => useGetUsers());
        await act(() => returnPromise)

        await waitFor(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled())//this fails
        
    });
```

here is another try and change I made in my test, but no luck:

```js
    test('when the call is a success', async () => {
        jest.mock('src/..', () => ({
            ...jest.requireActual('src/..'),
            userRequest: jest
                .fn()
                .mockImplementation(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve({data: ['a']}))),
        }));
        const { result, waitFor} = renderHook(() => useGetUsers());
        await waitFor(() => expect(ES.userRequest).toHaveBeenCalled())
    
    });
```

P.S. when I mock userRequest, I expect to have the return value as I mocked. but it fails. it goes to .catch instead

I tried to use waitForNextUpdate, but no luck. I would appreciate your help

Comment: You're overwriting your spy.  Just assert on `await waitFor(() => expect(ES.userRequest).toHaveBeenCalled())`

Comment: @possum I have removed spy. but it does not get into .then(). when I mock userRequest, I expect to have the return value as I mocked. but it fails. it goes to .catch

Comment: Yeah, all you're testing is the function being called and it's probably just ending there.    You probably want to be asserting on (with a `waitFor`) `result.current.state` to equal `['a']`

Comment: I changed it to be `await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.quotes.quotesData).toEqual(['a']), {timeout: 1000})` but still it gets into .catch

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useGetUsers } from '../useGetUsers';
import * as utils from '../useGetUsersUtils';

it('should work', async () => {
  const mockUserRequest = jest.spyOn(utils, 'userRequest');
  renderHook(() => useGetUsers());

  await waitFor(() => expect(mockUserRequest).toHaveBeenCalled())
});
```

I am not sure where is the `userRequest` placed in your code. As you can see from my import it is in different file then the hook.